# Angular2+ userid based restriction

Tags: angular

I'm creating an application where an user can enroll for a game.
When te user is enrolled for a game, the user will be put in a group.

Then the user can open the group. The url for the group is with route paramater "groupID": host/group/:groupID

For example: User 1 is enrolled for a group with groupID = 1. So he can open the group with host/group/1

What if User 2 (who is not enrolled for group 1) manipulates the url with host/group/1. How can I restrict this access?

Comment: You can use canActive at router layer or even you can check user authentication for the group before actual component called.

Comment: @user3145373ツ how can I get the groupID param in canActivate?

Comment: You can use RouterStateSnapshot in canActivate and from that you can fetch url.